# Cambios no se actualizan en componente VUE

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un componente de VUE padre llamado "rangos_mes", y este a su vez tiene un componente hijo llamado "rangos_mes_item".

Se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando agrego un nuevo item dando click en el botón "+", los valores que escribo en el nuevo item no se ven reflejados en el arreglo que tengo en mi objeto app (la lista de items).  Pero si modifico algún dato de los items que ya existían (inicializados en la lista por hardcode) sí se refleja.

Cuando miro por el depurador del navegador el objeto app.rangos, los datos de dia_inicial y dia_final de la línea que acabo de ingresar están en cero a pesar que le he escrito valores en los cuadros de texto.

Agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme.

Muchas gracias.

```js
Vue.component('rangos_mes', {
    props: [
        'rangos'
    ],
    template: `
        <div class="rangos_mes">
            <input type="button" value="+" @click="add" class="btn btn-primary rangos-mes-add">
            <table class="rangos_mes_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Dia inicial</th>
                    <th>Dia final</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <rangos_mes_item 
                    v-for="(rango, index) in this.rangos" 
                    :key="rango.id"
                    :dia_inicial="rango.dia_inicial" 
                    :dia_final="rango.dia_final"
                    :index="index"
                ></rangos_mes_item>
            </table>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        add: () => {
            rangos_mes_add();
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('rangos_mes_item', {
    props: ['dia_inicial', 'dia_final', 'index'],
    template: `
        <tr>
            <td><input type="number" v-model="dia_inicial" class="rangos_mes_dia"></td>
            <td><input type="number" v-model="dia_final" class="rangos_mes_dia"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="X" @click="del(index)"></td>
        </tr>
    `,
    methods: {
        del: (indice) => {
            rangos_mes_del( indice )
        }
    }
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        rangos: [
            {id: 1, dia_inicial: 1, dia_final: 5},
            {id: 2, dia_inicial: 6, dia_final: 15},
            {id: 3, dia_inicial: 16, dia_final: 30}
        ]
    }
})

function rangos_mes_add () {
    app.rangos.push({id: 4, dia_inicial: 0, dia_final: 0})
}

function rangos_mes_del ( indice ) {
    app.rangos.splice(indice, 1)
}
```

```css
div.rangos_mes {
    width: 400px;
    border: thin solid gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input.rangos-mes-add {
    margin: 5px;
}

table.rangos_mes_table {
    width: 100%;
}

input.rangos_mes_dia {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="rangos-mes.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="app">
        <rangos_mes v-bind:rangos="rangos"></rangos_mes>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="rangos-mes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, no es adecuado que interactúes con funciones externas a la instancia de Vue, lo natural sería que envies props a los componentes hijos e emitas eventos al componente padre, de hecho del modo que has implementado tu código tu data: `rangos` no está cambiando sus valores porque no están bindiados.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tienes algún ejemplo de la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con bus events, pero se hará tedioso, lo más adecuado sería que uses Vuex, podría hacer un ejemplo...

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo podría orientarte, es imprescindible manejar los conceptos de [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), porque te facilitará muchas situaciones, podría haberse hecho con bus events pero vuex te da una facilidad de hacerlo mantenible y escalable.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

// vuex store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // estado de la store
  state: {
    // estado inicial de los datos
    rangos: [
      { dia_inicial: 1, dia_final: 5 },
      { dia_inicial: 6, dia_final: 15 },
      { dia_inicial: 16, dia_final: 30 }
    ]
  },
  // mutaciones para cambios de estado síncronos
  mutations: {
    // agrega un rango al estado de los datos
    ADD_RANGO: state => {
      state.rangos.push({ dia_inicial: 0, dia_final: 0 });
    },
    // elimina un rango del estado de los datos de acuerdo al index
    DELETE_RANGO: (state, payload) => {
      state.rangos.splice(payload, 1);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("rangos-mes", {
  template: `
    <div class="rangos_mes">
      <input 
        @click="add"
        type="button" value="+"         
        class="btn btn-primary rangos-mes-add"
      >
      <table class="rangos_mes_table">
        <tr>
          <th>Dia inicial</th>
          <th>Dia final</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- no es necesario crear otro componente, basta hacerlo aquí para iterar las filas -->
        <tr v-for="(rango, index) in rangos" :key="index">
          <td>
            <input
              v-model.number="rango.dia_inicial"
              type="number"
              class="rangos_mes_dia"
            >
          </td>
          <td>
            <input             
              v-model.number="rango.dia_final"
              type="number"
              class="rangos_mes_dia"
            >
          </td>
          <td>
            <input 
              @click="del(index)"
              type="button" 
              class="btn btn-danger" 
              value="X"
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <pre style="background-color: #ccc">
        estado de rangos: {{ rangos }}
      </pre>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    // hace un commit a la mutación DELETE_RANGO de la store enviandole el index a borrar del estado
    del(index) {
      store.commit("DELETE_RANGO", index);
    },
    // hace un commit a la mutación ADD_RANGO de la store para agregar un nuevo rango al estado
    add() {
      store.commit("ADD_RANGO");
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // devuelve el estado en tiempo real con los datos de la store
    rangos() {
      return store.state.rangos;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <rangos-mes></rangos-mes>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Lo de Vuex aun me cuesta un poco, así que opté por la primera respuesta.

En el método Change del componente rangos-mes-item genero un evento para el componente rangos-mes:

```
change (tipo_dia) {

    switch (tipo_dia) {
        case 'inicial':
            this.$emit('change', tipo_dia, this.id, this.dia_ini);
            break;
        case 'final':
            this.$emit('change', tipo_dia, this.id, this.dia_fin);
            break;
    }
}
```

Y en el template del componente rangos-mes:

```
<rangos-mes-item 
    v-for="(rango, index) in rangos" 
    :key="rango.id"
    :dia-inicial="rango.dia_inicial" 
    :dia-final="rango.dia_final"
    :index="index"
    @change="change"
    @delete="del"
></rangos-mes-item>
```

Y en los métodos:

```
change (tipo_dia, id, value) {
    switch (tipo_dia) {
        case 'inicial':
            this.rangos[id].dia_inicial = parseInt(value);                    
            break;
        case 'final':
            this.rangos[id].dia_final = parseInt(value);
            break;
    }
}
```